# Inheritance can't call child class method

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

Hey i'm trying to call child class method(ChildClass extends SuperClass())

```
SuperClass s=new ChildClass();
s.childClassMethod();
```

It doesn't see the ChildClass method the only methods i can call are from SuperClass()
i know it's propably a stupid question but anyway cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's right, you can't see it because `s` is type `SuperClass` which doesn't have this method - this would obviously break [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) principle.

So you either have to change the code like `((ChildClass) s).childClassMethod();` or make `s` as `ChildClass` type.

Answer (score 3):

Compiler doesn't know what instance this reference would be pointing to at runtime so it will only allow you to access super class's accessible methods at compile time

**See**

- [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Answer (score 3):

The parent does not know anything about any new methods the child possesses.

```
public class SuperClass {
    // I have no method named "childClassMethod"...
}

public class ChildClass {
    public void childClassMethod() {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

`SuperClass` does not know about `childClassMethod()`. You would have to provide both classes with an interface or add that method to the parent and override it in the child.

Or, you could simply cast the object to the child class as others have suggested, but this can be unsafe.

```
((ChildClass) s).childClassMethod()
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because the super class does not have that method.

If you want the super class to be able to call the method, you need to make it abstract and give it that method.

The subclass is a form of the super class, the super class is not a form of the sub class.

Comment: i see so if i'll create a empty method in super class it will work?

Comment: @user1840040 yes, but you'll have to make the super class abstract, you can also make the method in the superclass, then override it in the subclass